# (MS SQL Server) Setting Case Statement Column Name With A Formula

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use a formula to set column names for case statements but the straightforward approach is not accepted. Here is the example of what I am attempting to do - is there a way to make this work?

```
select

ID

-- Pull DeDupe_Decision_Count for that ID last month (EOM_Date), where each ID has multiple rows in the data set for each data month

, sum(case when EOM_Date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))  
then DeDupe_Decision_Count end)  
as CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

-- Pulling the same for two months ago

, sum(case when EOM_Date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,-2,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))  
then DeDupe_Decision_Count end)  
as CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-2,DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

-- Pulling the same for three months ago

, sum(case when EOM_Date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(m,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))  
then DeDupe_Decision_Count end)  
as CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-2,DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))))

-- Would like to do the same for 12-24 months  
from Mytable  
group by ID
```

I would like to use the formula instead of a static date because this will be updated monthly and include 12-24 months of data. I could use variables and just name the columns last month, 2 months ago, 3 months ago, etc. but I would rather the column name be the date of the month.

Answer (score 0):

This requires dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'select
case

when EOM_Date = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)))

then ''DeDupe_Decision_Count''

end as '+ Quotename(CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(s, -1, Dateadd(mm, Datediff(m, 0, Getdate()), 0))))

PRINT @sql 

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I've seen dynamic queries mentioned when looking into this but haven't been able to make them work. I can take your example and change the fields that would normally come from my table to standalone and it will work but I don't know how to add from. Maybe I should have been more clear in my initial post. I've added more details to it now that will hopefully clear it up.